# rails erb line width

Tags: ruby-on-rails, erb

i currently try to call a javascript method with link_to_function.

```
<%= link_to_function( r.cls.to_s.split("#").last ,
"loadDetails('#{Base64.encode64(r.cls.to_s).strip}');"  )%>
```

The problem is i get a JS error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL
```

I assume this happens because rails puts some line breaks into my code:

```
    onclick="loadDetails('aHR0cDovL3d3dy5vd2wtb250b2xvZ2llcy5jb20vT250b2xvZ3kxMzUxNzAy

NTA5Lm93bCNjMzM=');; return false;"
```

I would like that link_to_funktion prints out linke-break-free output.

Do you know how to archieve this?

**PS:**

When i escape javascript it still returns:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL
```

Comment: escape javascript you need to do that

Comment: The `link_to` function doesn't modify the string you pass in. What's the value of `r.cls.to_s`?

Comment: URI
r.cls.to_s->
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13237139/rails-erb-line-width#comment